# TypeScript 2.0 method type guards?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

In TypeScript 2.0, why can I have a **function** type guard:

```
function hasValue<T>(value: T | undefined): value is T { return value !== undefined; }
```

But not a **method** type guard?:

```
export class Maybe<T> {
    constructor(public value: T | undefined) {}

    hasValue(): this.value is T { return this.value !== undefined; }
}
```

error on `hasValue()`:

> '{' or ';' expected.

Comment: Is this related to TypeScript 2.0? Anyway, the identifier in `value in T` must be some identifier in scope, such as a parameter. This holds true whether or not the guard is on a function or a method. You can write your guard as `hasValue<T>(value) value is T { return value !== undefined; }`, and call it as `if (this.hasValue(this.value)) ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1) When using `this` when declaring the return type then it's used as [polymorphic this type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) and not as a reference to the instance of the class.

2) [The docs on this matter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) clearly state that:

> A predicate takes the form parameterName is Type, where parameterName
>   must be the name of a parameter from the current function signature.

If you use `this.parameterName` then it isn't "a parameter from the current function signature".
You could argue that they could add it but then:

3) Type guards are functions which check a type and not a variable.
As the type itself isn't a part of the class then it makes sense that the type guard function won't be a part of the class as well.